# Android アプリが強制終了してしまい、オプティカルフローが使えない

Tags: java, android, opencv

OpenCVのオプティカルフローを使ったAndroidアプリの開発をしています。

OpenCV for Androidにオプティカルフローのサンプルがないため、先日下記のサイトを参考にしてオプティカルフローを動かそうとしましたが「問題が発生したため終了します」というメッセージと共に強制終了してしまいます。

http://pukulab.blog.fc2.com/blog-category-7.html

様々なサイトを見たのですが解決できません。どうぞよろしくお願いします。

エラーは以下の通りです。

```
11-27 17:03:44.492 768-801/? E/WindowManager: Starting window AppWindowToken{4449a3f8 token=Token{429fff58 ActivityRecord{426bb2b8 u0 jp.wings.nikkeibp.eyegraphic/.CameraActivity t28}}} timed out
11-27 17:05:41.702 7090-7090/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: jp.wings.nikkeibp.eyegraphic, PID: 7090
                                             java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:()J
                                                 at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
                                                 at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:447)
                                                 at org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f.<init>(MatOfPoint2f.java:12)
                                                 at jp.wings.nikkeibp.eyegraphic.CameraActivity.<init>(CameraActivity.java:85)
                                                 at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

ソースコードはこのようになります。
CameraActivity.java

```
// Java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

// OpenCV
import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfFloat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfInt;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint3f;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Point3;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.TermCriteria;
import org.opencv.features2d.Features2d;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.opencv.video.Video;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;

// UI
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements     CvCameraViewListener2 {
private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";

// カメラビューのインスタンス
// CameraBridgeViewBase は JavaCameraView/NativeCameraView のスーパークラス
private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;

// カメラ画像保存用
private Mat image, image_small;

// オプティカルフロー用
private Mat image_prev, image_next;//画像比較
private MatOfPoint2f pts_prev,pts_next;//Point2f（座標　）計算結果の格納？

// OpenCVライブラリのロード
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            // 読み込みが成功したらカメラプレビューを開始
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                break;
            }
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

// コンストラクタ
public CameraActivity() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
    pts_prev = new MatOfPoint2f();　//エラーで指摘される行
    pts_next = new MatOfPoint2f();
}

// 起動時
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eyeglance);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    //camera_viewはeyeglanceのレイアウトに定義したプレビュー用の画面
    // カメラビューのインスタンス(mOpenCvCameraView)を変数にバインド
    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    // リスナーの登録＊
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

}



// 再開時,activity前
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallback);

}

// 停止時,activity後
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null) mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

// 破棄時,一番最後
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null) mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

// カメラ開始時
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    image = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    image_small = new Mat(height/8, width/8, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    image_prev = new Mat(image_small.rows(), image_small.cols(), image_small.type());
    image_next = new Mat(image_small.rows(), image_small.cols(), image_small.type());
}

// カメラ停止時
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
}



// 画像取得時
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    // 縮小
    image = inputFrame.rgba();
    Imgproc.resize(image, image_small, image_small.size(), 0, 0, Imgproc.INTER_NEAREST);

    // グレースケール

    Mat gray = new Mat(image_small.rows(), image_small.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(image_small, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    // 特徴点抽出
    MatOfPoint features = new MatOfPoint();
    Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, features, 50, 0.01, 10);

    // 特徴点が見つかった
    if (features.total() > 0) {
        // 過去のデータが存在する
        if (pts_prev.total() > 0) {
            // 現在のデータ
            gray.copyTo(image_next);
            pts_next = new MatOfPoint2f(features.toArray());

            // オプティカルフロー算出
            MatOfByte status = new MatOfByte();
            MatOfFloat err = new MatOfFloat();
            Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(image_prev, image_next, pts_prev, pts_next, status, err);

            // 表示
            long flow_num = status.total();
            if (flow_num > 0) {
                List<Byte>  list_status = status.toList();
                List<Point> list_features_prev = pts_prev.toList();
                List<Point> list_features_next = pts_next.toList();
                double scale_x = image.cols() / image_small.cols();
                double scale_y = image.rows() / image_small.rows();
                for (int i = 0; i < flow_num; i++) {
                    if (list_status.get(i) == 1) {
                        Point p1 = new Point();
                        p1.x = list_features_prev.get(i).x * scale_x;
                        p1.y = list_features_prev.get(i).y * scale_y;
                        //Core.circle(image, p1, 3, new Scalar(255,0,0), -1, 8, 0 );
                        Point p2 = new Point();
                        p2.x = list_features_next.get(i).x * scale_x;
                        p2.y = list_features_next.get(i).y * scale_y;
                        //Core.circle(image, p2, 3, new Scalar(255,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );

                        // フロー描画
                        int thickness = 5;
                        Core.line(image, p1, p2, new Scalar(0,255,0), thickness);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // 過去のデータ
        gray.copyTo(image_prev);
        pts_prev = new MatOfPoint2f(features.toArray());
    }

    return image;
 }
}
```

MatOfPoint2f.java

```
package org.opencv.core;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MatOfPoint2f extends Mat {
// 32FC2
private static final int _depth = CvType.CV_32F;
private static final int _channels = 2;

public MatOfPoint2f() {
    super(); //エラーで指摘される行
}

protected MatOfPoint2f(long addr) {
    super(addr);
    if( !empty() && checkVector(_channels, _depth) < 0 )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incompatible Mat");
    //FIXME: do we need release() here?
}

public static MatOfPoint2f fromNativeAddr(long addr) {
    return new MatOfPoint2f(addr);
}

public MatOfPoint2f(Mat m) {
    super(m, Range.all());
    if( !empty() && checkVector(_channels, _depth) < 0 )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incompatible Mat");
    //FIXME: do we need release() here?
}

public MatOfPoint2f(Point...a) {
    super();
    fromArray(a);
}

public void alloc(int elemNumber) {
    if(elemNumber>0)
        super.create(elemNumber, 1, CvType.makeType(_depth, _channels));
}

public void fromArray(Point...a) {
    if(a==null || a.length==0)
        return;
    int num = a.length;
    alloc(num);
    float buff[] = new float[num * _channels];
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++) {
        Point p = a[i];
        buff[_channels*i+0] = (float) p.x;
        buff[_channels*i+1] = (float) p.y;
    }
    put(0, 0, buff); //TODO: check ret val!
}

public Point[] toArray() {
    int num = (int) total();
    Point[] ap = new Point[num];
    if(num == 0)
        return ap;
    float buff[] = new float[num * _channels];
    get(0, 0, buff); //TODO: check ret val!
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
        ap[i] = new Point(buff[i*_channels], buff[i*_channels+1]);
    return ap;
}

public void fromList(List<Point> lp) {
    Point ap[] = lp.toArray(new Point[0]);
    fromArray(ap);
}

public List<Point> toList() {
    Point[] ap = toArray();
    return Arrays.asList(ap);
 }
}
```

Mat.java

```
public Mat()
{

    nativeObj = n_Mat();　//エラーで指摘される行

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mat クラス用のnativeメソッドの実体がロードできていないようです。

原因はいろいろ考えられますが、

- nativeライブラリ(拡張子が.soのファイル)が適切にapkに含まれているか
- ビルドで生成された.soファイルのABIが適切なもの(ARMで実行できるもの)になっているかるか
- nativeライブラリを適切に`System.loadLibrary()`しているか

等を確認してみてください。

Comment: 返事が遅れてしまい申し訳ありません。
ご回答ありがとうございます。共有ライブラリが正しくロードされていなかったみたいです。 その後正しく起動したのですがしばらくしてまた別のエラーがでてしまいました。